# Form load change another form element properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Current, Form1 will finish parsing but open up more forms depending on the amount of displays you have connected, so 2 displays will make 2 new instances of Form2.

Form2 is just a Form which has a WebBrowser loaded within it. I code nothing on Form2 whatsoever.

Before I Show() Form2, I set some properties, such as full width and height, so that form being opened takes up the full screen of that monitor. How do I access Form2.WebBrowser1.Url from Form1? I need Form1 to make it load a different URL per screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either:-

- pass the URL in on the constructor or
- have a public property on the form

Depends on whether you just want to change it once the form has loaded.

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    //This is the Constructor
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    //This is an overloaded constructor that takes a url argument
    public Form2(string URL )
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Store the URL For Later
        URLToDisplay = URL

    }


    //Property that you can access any where you have a reference to the form instance
    public int URLToDisplay { get; set; }

}
```

using the constructor above you can then do this....

```
    Form2 frm = new Form2("www.google.co.uk");
    frm.Show();
```

Comment: Yes it deffinately will change sooner or later, so once I can get the argument passed through, I can make it read from an XML file. Which is the constructor?

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning, I didn't realise where I could find the constructor, I found it in the end, it's all making more sense now. I did exactly what you suggested above before I saw it, but just because I clicked the wrong thing and found the Form2.cs file.

Comment: Not a problem.  I am on a mission to get more reputation points so these questions are great.  and being mostly a vb guy it's good for me to exercise my c# a bit.